# How to access the filters referenced in the Vue API?

Tags: vue.js

The Vue API lists a bunch of filters as though they are available out-the-box:

https://011.vuejs.org/api/filters.html

But I'm getting `failed to resolve filter` errors.  Is there a way to switch these on or am I getting something else wrong?

At the moment I am simply referencing one of the listed filters from my template:

```
{{lic.assignedusercount}} {{lic.assignedusercount | pluralize user}}
```

Comment: did you tried user as string? `pluralize 'user'`

Comment: That documentation is for Vue version `0.11`. There are no filters available out of the box in the most current version of Vue `2.x`. Here's the current documentation for filters: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html

Comment: @thanksd I was just coming to this conclusion with further googling, good to have it confirmed though.  Bad they removed what looks like a great feature...

Comment: There are probably a bunch of libraries that are just default filters for Vue. Here's the first one I found: https://github.com/freearhey/vue2-filters

Answer (score 1):

For completeness - this references a now out-of-date version of Vue.  The new version does not include any filters you have to build your own, or import an open source set.